# Play framework + Scala: Inject dependency using Action Composition

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I'm setting up a Play! app for our API. This API encapsulates different services. I want to inject these services inside an action but only the ones required for that particular endpoint. Something like:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = (UsersAction andThen OrdersAction) {
    // boom UsersService and OrdersService is available here
    for {
      users <- usersService.list
      orders <- ordersService.list
    } yield "whatever"
  }
}
```

I've been playing with this idea and using ActionTransformers I'm able to transform the incoming Request to a request that has a given service, but I don't see how I can make that generic enough so I can compose these actions in an arbitrary order without create ActionTransformers for all the possible combinations of WrapperRequests.

Maybe action composition is not the best way to achieve this. I'm all ears.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, the code above is pseudocode, the ideal scenario, in which usersService and ordersService are made available to that scope (implicits? I don't know). If that's not possible, then whatever adds the less amount of noise of top of that sample that would work.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code that shows your example of `UsersAction` and `OrdersAction` (a simplified version)

Comment: That's just pseudocode really. I've been playing with Action Composition trying to make something work following the examples here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: The reason I ask is that I do not see how you intend to make `usersService` and `ordersService` available. Where do you want to specify them and how do you want to make them available to the body of your action?

Comment: That's part of the question ^^U
Meaning, something like in that pseudocode would be ideal, then we'd have to add more code as required to make it compile. Sorry for the confusion. I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could get to your question is this:

```
def index =
  new UsersAction with OrdersAction {
    def body =
      for {
        users <- userService.list
        orders <- orderService.list
      } yield Ok("whatever")
  }
```

The implementation is quite straight forward

```
trait CustomAction extends Action[AnyContent] {
  def body: Future[Result]

  def apply(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Result] = body
  val parser = BodyParsers.parse.anyContent
}

trait UsersAction extends CustomAction {
  val userService: UserService = ???
}
trait OrdersAction extends CustomAction {
  val orderService: OrderService = ???
}
```

These are the other parts I used to get it to compile:

```
trait User
trait Order

trait UserService {
  def list: Future[Seq[User]]
}

trait OrderService {
  def list: Future[Seq[Order]]
}
```

Comment: Woah, thanks! I'm gonna mark it as accepted.

The only problem I see with this approach (I think) is that we lose the ability to do Action.asycn { } et al. Could this be solved?

Comment: It is `async`, the body is typed as a `Future[Result]`

Answer (score 0):

You can inject by guice, spring or what you want. 
Example for guice.
Just change the object to class:

```scala
class Application @Inject(userAction:UsersAction,ordersAction:OrdersAction) extends Controller {
  def index = (UsersAction andThen OrdersAction) {
    // boom UsersService and OrdersService is available here
    for {
      users <- usersService.list
      orders <- ordersService.list
    } yield "whatever"
  }
}
```

You have to override in Global:

```scala
object Global extends GlobalSettings{

 private lazy val injector = Guice.createInjector(new CommonModule)

 override def getControllerInstance[A](clazz: Class[A]) = {
    injector.getInstance(clazz)
  }

}
```

```scala
class CommonModule extends AbstractModule{

  protected def configure() {
    bind(classOf[UsersAction]).to(classOf[UsersActionImpl])
    bind(classOf[OrdersAction]).to(classOf[OrdersActionImpl])
  }

}
```

In route file add @ to controllers:

```
GET /service  @controllers.Application.index
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking to inject each dependency on an endpoint basis, and not globally in the controller. In other words, I only want a certain endpoint to have access to a given dependency without making that dependency available for endpoints in the same controller.

Comment: Why not using different controllers then?

Comment: If you want request specific service - just use [factory method design pattern](or modified version with input parameter), or providers. In play world - you can not use request scope guice providers - but you can implement it.